# Chrome shadow-root applying strange CSS rule

Tags: css, google-chrome, shadow-dom

I'm working on some CSS, and in chrome (with or without inspector console open) chrome is applying a weird inline stylesheet in the shadow-root element, despite the fact that I have DOM shadow-root turned off in the chrome settings. Even stranger, It's adding a `display: none` to several custom classes that I have in my stylesheet; as in, rules that I named and wrote, not browser default rules. This does not happen globally across all chrome browsers, nor even chrome browsers on the same type of device. This only happens on chrome in one of the Macbooks I use to work on the website. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adblock,if you have any, can cause such thing. Toggle it on/off at chrome://extensions to see the changes

Comment: [Adblock Plus forum](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25683)